# Reading x,y values from a .txt file in c#

Tags: c#, indexing

I'm trying to read x and y values from a text file into a string array where the line is being split on the ','
However, when I run this code I get an error saying the index was out of the bounds of the array on the first element. I've tried using temporary strings to store the data and then convert them but I still get the same error on the second element. here is my code I have implemented without the temporary strings.

```
string line;
while ((line = coordStream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] temp = new string[2];
   temp[0] = "";
   temp[1] = "";
   temp = line.Split(',');
   trees[count].X = Convert.ToInt16(temp[0]);
   trees[count].Y = Convert.ToInt16(temp[1]);
   count++;
 }
```

Here is the code with the temporary storage too:

```
string line;
while ((line = coordStream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] temp = new string[2];
   temp[0] = "";
   temp[1] = "";
   temp = line.Split(',');
   string xCoord = temp[0];
   string yCoord = temp[1];
   trees[count].X = Convert.ToInt16(xCoord);
   trees[count].Y = Convert.ToInt16(yCoord);
   count++;
 }
```

I know this seems a trivial error but I cannot seem to get this working. If I debug and step through the array manually it works but when I don't step through it(i.e let the program run) these errors are thrown

EDIT: The first 10 lines of data are as follows:

> > 654,603
> >
> > 640,583
> >
> > 587,672
> >
> > 627,677
> >
> > 613,711
> >
> > 612,717
> >
> > 584,715
> >
> > 573,662
> >
> > 568,662
> >
> > 564,687

There are no empty lines in the text file.

As pointed out by Jon Skeet, removing the temp assignments seems to have fixed this error. However even with the assignments it should still have worked. The following code sample inside the while loop works:

```
string[] temp;
temp = line.Split(',');
trees[count].X = Convert.ToInt16(temp[0]);
trees[count].Y = Convert.ToInt16(temp[1]);
count++;
```

The number of trees is known but I'd like to thank everyone for their input. Expect more questions in the near future :D

Comment: Show us an example of your input data. I'd guess you have a blank line at the end or something. Try using a String.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(line) in there somewhere.

Comment: Check the first line returned isn't empty before trying to split it.

Comment: Why are you creating an array which you're then ignoring? Anything you've assigned to `temp` *before* the later assignment is pointless. Just use `string[] temp = line.Split(',');`...

Comment: where do you set the size of trees?

Comment: Also give us a part of your text file. I think the problem is not with the code but with the file.

Comment: what line is the exception being thrown on?

Comment: What line of code gives you the error? Is it possible that your `trees` array isn't allocated large enough?

Comment: What about count and trees? Maybe count is too big or trees not big enought.

Comment: The issue has been sorted. but there are 48 Tree objects in an array of Trees. All initialised on Load();

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `List<Point>` for your `trees` collection instead of an array. This will help if you don't know the correct count upfront.

```
var trees = new List<Point>();
while (...)
{
    ...
    trees.Add(new Point(x, y));
}
```

The second possible issue is when the input line does not contain valid data (for example, is empty). Often the last line with data ends with a newline thus the last line is empty.

```
while ((line = coordStream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var temp = line.Split(',');
    if (temp.Length != 2)
        continue;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lineContents = File.ReadAllLines("").Select(line => line.Split(',')).Where(x => x.Count() == 2);
var allTrees = lineContents.Select(x => new Trees() { X = Convert.ToInt16(x[0]), Y = Convert.ToInt16(x[1]) });
```

Comment: All this does is show off how good a programmer *you* are, it doesn't help to further the understanding of the OP.

Comment: @KingCronus You don't need to upvote for this but, don't you think  it is a little bit harsh

Comment: @KingCronus how do you know the OP doesn't understand the code posted until he says so himself? Don't make premeditated decisions of what somebody is capable of before they say so themselves.

Comment: Fair enough @LukeHennerley, agree to disagree. The fact that the OP has used the method they have done to complete this task (and is unable to debug it) is more than enough information to establish that simply providing a more complicated method isn't the best idea. I've removed my downvote, as I said, agree to disagree. I've seen plenty of this sort of answer be accepted, only to be copy-pasted into production code without understanding what is going on.

Comment: I understand it perfectly and it seems a great solution. Thank you very much for the input(I do try and keep my code efficient but it wasn't until I learned Python this year that I learned how to optimise code to less amounts of line of code but as I'm coding in C#, I tend to keep it simple ;) )

Comment: @KingCronus I also understand the solution and think it is a great way to go about solving the issue in hand. Congratulations Luke, you are a God amongst men.